# When is an account displayed on the Unity login screen?

Tags: users, unity, display-manager, accounts

What are the exact rules for an account to be offered for login on the Unity login screen?

I figured out:

- Locked accounts are still displayed
- Without password are still displayed
- Marked as /bin/nologin are still displayed

However, the majority of the locked accounts like root, several service accounts etc are not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the user ID.

Only accounts with an ID >= 500 are displayed on the login and 'Accounts' screens.

You can change this minimum ID value by changing `minimum-uid` in `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` to your preference.

http://linuxsecuritysolutions.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/linux-user-types/